# How can I pause jQuery until a condition is met?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, conditional-statements

The condition is that a SPACE is typed.... It's inside a CASE statement:

```
        case KEY.ATSIGN:

                        clearTimeout(timeout);
                        //alert(event.keyCode);
                        while(event.keyCode != 32) {
                            alert(event.keyCode);
                            timeout = setTimeout(onChange, options.delayLong);

                        }

            break;
```

32 is the ascii for space... I am trying to get the subset matching feature to work in jQuery only AFTER an @ sign is typed.... Hence the case statement KEY.ATSIGN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an event handler on the keypress event on your input element and evaluate what key was pressed.

http://api.jquery.com/keypress/